# Simplification of hypergeometric Function

Tags: co.combinatorics, probability-distributions, generating-functions, hypergeometric-functions, mathematical-software

First of all I am not at all a math expert, but I have some working knowledge.
That said, please excuse "dumb" questions.

I am looking at the following process: Assume you are on the 2-Dimensional Integer Lattice (but only the non-negative part), so all pairs $\left\lbrace(m,n) \mid m\in \mathbb{N}, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\rbrace,~\text{where}~ 0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now you start at some Point $(m,n)$ and you repeatedly flip a fair coin to decrease either $n$ by 1 or $m$ by 1. You stop the process whenever you either hit the left boundary $(0,n)$ or the bottom boundary $(m,0)$. I am interested in the resulting reachability distribution over the pairs where the process terminates given we started at some point $(m,n)$.

To frame it in a different way, given the following pseudo-code of a probabilistic program:

```
while ( m > 0 and n > 0):
  if flip(1/2):
    m = m-1
  else:
    n = n-1
```

I am interested in the final distribution represented by this probabilistic program.

Doing my calculations (seemingly correct), I see that this process seems to be related to hypergeometric distributions. I encode the distribution by means of a probability generating function

$$G_{m,n}(t_m,t_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} t_m^i\frac{1}{2^{m+n-i}}\binom{m+n-i-1}{n-1} ~+~ \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_n^i\frac{1}{2^{m+n-i}}\binom{m+n-i-1}{m-1}$$

Now I was looking for "closed-forms" (or at least factorized forms) of this formula so I tried to enter $G_{m,n}(t_m, t_n)$ in Mathematica with global assumptions that the variables $i, m, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Don't be confused, for implementation reasons I used $a,b$ for $m,n$ and $m,n$ instead of $t_m, t_n$.

```
s[a_, b_] := 
 Sum[m^i Binomial[a + b - i - 1, b - 1]/2^(a + b - i), {i, 1, a}] + 
 Sum[n^i Binomial[a + b - i - 1, a - 1]/2^(a + b - i), {i, 1, b}]
```

Computing `s[a,b]` where I plug in concrete numbers for $a$ and $b$ works perfectly fine. However when I want to compute `s[a,b]` for symbolic $a$ and $b$ it simplifies to

```
2^(1 - a - b) m Binomial[-2 + a + b, -1 + b] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - a, 2 - a - b, 2 m] + 
2^(1 - a - b) n Binomial[-2 + a + b, -1 + a] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - b, 2 - a - b, 2 n]
```

Trying to substitute values like `s[a,b]/.a->1/b->1` leads to wrong results.

Now to my actual question:

Is there a closed-form for these sums in (n or m respectively)? Something like $\sum_{i=0}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. As shown above, Mathematica suggests a hypergeometric function which does not seem to be correct for all cases of $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$.

A big thank you to all the people considering this question, and trying to help me out.

Comment: [MathOverflow guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer)  have this: "avoid trying to answer questions which [...] request answers to multiple questions." In this case there are 5 (!) questions in one post. Some of these questions concerns Mathematica (which sometimes gives generic and not always correct answers), and such questions should rather be asked on a Mathematica forum or addressed to the Wolfram company.

Comment: thank you for providing me this guideline, I have adapted my question to meet the requirements, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

The singularity of $s(a,b)$ at the point $(a,b)=(1,1)$ can be avoided by approaching that point from the line $a=b$:

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 1}s(a,a)=\frac{m+n}{2}.$$

---

**Alternative approach:**

You need to avoid taking the limit $x\rightarrow 0$ of $ _2F_1(1,x,x;m)$, which is undefined. So to get the correct answer, decompose
$$s(a, b)=s_1(a, b)+ s_2(a, b),$$
$$s_1(a, b)=\sum _{i=1}^a \frac{m^i \binom{a+b-i-1}{b-1}}{2^{a+b-i}}= m \,2^{-a-b+1} \binom{a+b-2}{b-1} \, _2F_1(1,1-a;-a-b+2;2 m),$$
$$s_2(a, b)=\sum _{i=1}^b \frac{n^i \binom{a+b-i-1}{a-1}}{2^{a+b-i}}= n \, 2^{-a-b+1} \binom{a+b-2}{a-1} \, _2F_1(1,1-b;-a-b+2;2 n),$$
and then evaluate the limits $a,b\rightarrow 1$ in the order
$$\lim_{b\rightarrow 1}\lim_{a\rightarrow 1}s_1(a, b)=\tfrac{1}{2}m,\qquad\lim_{a\rightarrow 1}\lim_{b\rightarrow 1}s_2(a, b)=\tfrac{1}{2}n.$$

Comment: I see that this trick avoids the problem of obtaining wrong results. Somehow this is still in contradiction to the hypergeometric function being a correct "simplified" result of the sum expression. Also for a probability generating function the limit from below should always be defined as naturally the total mass of a probability distribution sums up to 1. But here it really depends on the order of taking the limits, and that I have to decompose the function beforehand. This seems somewhat unpleasant to me.

Comment: [MathOverflow guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer)  have this: "avoid trying to answer questions which [...] request answers to multiple questions." In this case there are 5 (!) questions in one post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out, that my issue was to do separate substitutions.

Whenever you do

```
s[a,b]/.{a->x, b->y}
```

for any pair of $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, the result is correct.

The issue seems to be that `s[a,b]/.{a->x, b->y} != s[a,b]/.a->x/.b->y` as Mathematica simplifies the expressions in between the substitution steps.

Thus, I guess that indeed the closed-form given by Mathematica is correct.